# Assistance with a regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to get regex patterns.  I am trying to match {some tag=1,7,12,13} in retrieving just the numbers OR strings after = .

{some tag=1, some string, test, 6}

should return:

```
1
some string
test
6
```

Thanks for any help.

I've tried matching any tag with `/{(.*?)}/` and exploding, but was hoping there is a simple one liner solution.

Comment: There are technically one-liners you could use, but they would really just be a bunch of function calls passing results directly into other function calls. The result would be really ugly and difficult to maintain if you ever come back to your code in the future. If you really want a "one-liner", then define your own function that will take care of all of the steps behind the scenes. Even if your function body is multiple lines long, the function call itself will only ever be one line. Code that is easy to read and maintain is far more important than having fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't sure what might be desired quite, yet maybe this expression might be OK to look into, with which you can likely build or modify as you like so:

```
$re = '/{[^=]*=\K|(?:([^,\r\n]*)(?=,|\s*}))*/s';
$str = '{some tag=1, some string, test, 6}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$output = '';
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[0]) {
        $output .= $value[0];
    }
    // or you can use arrays and other forms of data and output other desired things.
}

var_dump($output);
```

#### Output

```
string(20) "1 some string test 6"
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1SCUID/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/1SCUID/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: This actually works perfectly, I can separate the output string with explode from there.  Thanks a lot!  I messed around with a cheat sheet and had: preg_match_all("/{menu id=(.*)}/", $text, $matches); which worked, a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capturing group and make use of the `\G` anchor.

```
(?:\{[^=\r\n]+=|\G(?!^))(?=.*\}$)\h*([^,}\r\n]+)\h*[,}]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `\{[^=\r\n]+=` Match `{`, 1+ times any char other than `=` or a newline
- `|` Or
- `\G(?!^))` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `(?=.*\}$)` Assert `}` at the end of the string
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^,}\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `,` `}` and a newline
- `)` Close group
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `[,}]` Match `,` or `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ZbJ2z/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/T74kr)

For example

```
$re = '/(?:\{[^=\r\n]+=|\G(?!^))(?=.*\}$)\h*([^,}\r\n]+)\h*[,}]/';
$str = '{some tag=1, some string, test, 6}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => some string
    [2] => test
    [3] => 6
)
```

If you want to full string use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and the array from `$matches[1]`

```
echo implode (' ', $matches[1]);
```

Result

```
1 some string test 6
```